# Assistant editor only opening viewController and not another class

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have some outlets that I want to link to another class that I have as below[image]

[image]

and I want to add my labels in the ActivityTableViewCell, however, the assistant editor only opens the viewController for me.
How do I link it to this class?

UPDATE:
when I add another editor screen, it kinda deactivates the first one (as you see in the pic below) and can't drag anything on it

[image]

Comment: if you are facing issue with assistant editor you can manual write the outlets or action in your table cell class and then do the following steps. 1. assign class to your table cell from Identity inspector 2. then click on show the connection inspector and drag your outlet to view for connection

Comment: @MuhammadNawaz I'm sorry how do I assign class to my table cell from identity inspector? is it using the custom class?

Comment: In code your cell is an ActivityTableViewCell. But in the storyboard your prototype cell is not. Hence no outlet connection is possible.

Comment: @matt sorry could you explain more?
(I'm sorry I'm new to using xcode)

Comment: Click on `myCell` on the left, and then switch to the Identity inspector. If it says UITableViewCell, that's the cause. It needs to say ActivityTableViewCell.

Comment: @matt Thanks the problem was my class wasn't connected to the storyboard as your earlier comment
Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured it out!

[image]

on the storyboard select your tableview.
Then drop down to the tableviewcell.
Then drop down to the Content view when you have selected the Content View the UITableViewCell will show up at the assistant editor.

This is what i see at the Assistant editor when it select the Content View.

[image]

Comment If you have a question :D!

Comment: Thats the thing. I can't !!!!
when I added another window, it kinda deactivates the other one (goes gray) and when I drag it to that window nothing happens

Comment: muhammad's comment does not work either?

Comment: I'm sorry how do I assign class to my table cell from identity inspector? is it using the custom class? and for the connection, I only see the option to drag which if I don't have my screen there I can't link it to anything manually

Comment: I edited my answer this works for me!

Comment: hmmm it still isn't working for me.

Comment: could I be defining my class wrong?
I mean my class is a ActivityTableViewCell class is a UITableViewCell. Should I be doing anything else with the class?

Comment: Have you connected it to the Custom Class?

Comment: Have you set the style to Custom at identety inspector?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239887/discussion-between-bear-and-nater).

Comment: That was the problem!
wasn't connected. Oh my god thanks so much for the help
Sorry I'm new to this and still haven't mastered xcode

Comment: We have all been there no problem